# Share individual copies of a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I created a Google Sheets file which I want to share with my co-workers so each one has his own copy. So far the only way I found is to share the file, however this doesn't work for me because each co-worker has his own information, and the information used in the file is not for collaboration.

Is there a way to send a copy of the file so that each one has his own copy, like the way you would send an Excel file over email so that everyone would have their own copy?

Answer (score 1):

When you email an Excel file you are actually sending someone a copy of the file.

To duplicate this, you would create multiple copies of the Google Spreadsheet and then share each copy.

Comment: Or just sharing a single document with them all - with viewing permission - and telling them to save a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Old as dirt, but works....Get the shareable link, and append the end with /copy, as in:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vafdsaffgtrtewtfdgdsFDZ85eMHdGU/**COPY**

This will force each user to create their own local copy!

Answer (score -1):

Try using Doctopus it will create multiple copies for individuals. Normally used in classroom setting to assign work.

Comment: Have you tried it Jason? If yes, why don't you add some references or howtos?